# Determine if Week Number is Even or Odd

Tags: java

How can you check a date to see if its week number is even or odd?

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
Date currentdate = new Date();
cal.setTime(date);
int week = cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
```

For example, if return current date is 1/6/2015 then return string Even; for an odd week number return string Odd.

Comment: Well you've got as far as getting the week number. Do you know how to tell whether a number is odd or even? And do you know how to respond to a condition to return one value or another? (Hint: I'd use a conditional expression... `return [condition here] ? "Even" : "Odd";`)

Comment: You already have the week number. Are you asking how to figure out whether a number is odd or even?

Comment: @ Jon Thanks for the hint, I guess Shriram replied with same expression below. but thanks anyway. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

System.out.println(week % 2 == 0 ? "Even" : "Odd");

Answer (score 1):

Try this `if(week%2==0){
return "Even";}
return " Odd";`